# Cardioid and Integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to find the integral of the function f(x,y) = y over the region D which is inside the cardioid r = 2 + 2 $\cos \theta$ and outside the circle r=2?

I am unable to set the limits of the integrals. Please explain. The answer in my textbook for this comes out to be 22/3.

Please show me the answer with steps along with proper integral limits set and reason for choosing those limits?

Comment: $\theta\$ must lie between -pi/2 to pi/2 which I can write by putting the outer limit to vary from 0 to pi/2 and then multiplying the area by 2 to cover the whole area. In my textbook it's being taken from 0 to pi/2 and I am confused for why the area is not multiplied by 2 as the cardioid is above the below the x axis. Please suggest the solution

Answer (score 0):

Your region is symmetric around the x-axis.  The integral of $f(x,y) = y$ will be $0$ over any such interval.

Anyway,

convert to polar

$x = r\cos \theta\\
y = r\sin\theta$

limits for theta.

$2 + 2\cos\theta = 2\\
\theta = 0\\
\pm \frac {\pi}{2}$

$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_2^{2+2\cos\theta} r^2\sin\theta \ dr\ d\theta\\
\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac 13 ((2+2\cos\theta)^3 - 8)\sin\theta \ dr\ d\theta\\
\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}8\cos\theta\sin\theta + 8\cos^2\theta\sin\theta + \frac {8}{3}\cos^3\sin\theta\ d\theta$

If we added the constraint that we are also limited to the upper half-plane, $\frac {22}{3}$ is plausible.

$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}8\cos\theta\sin\theta + 8\cos^2\theta\sin\theta + \frac {8}{3}\cos^3\sin\theta\ d\theta = \frac {8}{2} + \frac{8}{3} + \frac {8}{12} = \frac {22}3$